# How can I lock a person who gives a particular gesture and might go out of sight in Kinect?

Tags: image-processing, kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect

I'm making this program using Kinect SDK. I want to track the skeleton of a person who gives a particular gesture. I want to keep on tracking him even if he goes out of the sight of the kinect camera. Is there any way to do this using Kinect SDK or anyother libraries for Kinect?

Comment: How can the brain see what the eyes can't see?

Comment: @ChrisLava: Funny enough, that is exactly what is going on all the time. The brain "sees" things that aren't really visible. And while you can perhaps not "track" things you can't see, you can still retain memory of it, and predict where it could be, to reacquire the tracking/labelling as soon as the object is visible again.

Comment: @Anish: Your question is a bit vague. Can you please be more specific about your problem. What have you done so far? What is not working? etc.

Comment: @HannesOvrén I don't know how can I be more specific? And I have written a program which locks the person on giving a particular gesture. But, It doesn't lock if the person goes out of sight. I just want to know the logic how to do this... That's why I didn't post anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is there any way to do this using Kinect SDK or any other libraries for Kinect?"

**No.**

If you are not in the vision area of the Kinect sensor - you are not being detected. 
If you are not being detected - Kinect cannot give input which refers to you. 
Without input which refers to you - your location is unknown.

**But - is achievable** 
You could achieve triangulation of the location of the person by using the kinect built-in microphone array. but this is a technology in dippers...
you can read more here: [triangulation by sound distribution](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=6181458)

Comment: Damn... I researched a lot. I couldn't find anything. Thanks though.